# Transferring wordpress to zeus server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, server-error, zeus

I have been trying to transfer a wordpress site created on godaddy linux server & after everything is complete when trying to transfer the site on register 365 hosting on a zeus server, the site is giving a server error Error code: 500 the log file says:

> [2013-08-02 01:18:44] [access_compat:error] [client 182.64.175.19:15992] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/httpd/icons/unknown.gif, referer http://eventworks.ie/dev/
>
> [autoindex:error] (13)Permission denied: [client 182.64.79.214:43404] AH01275: Can't open directory for index: /content/Hosting/e/v/eventworks.ie/web/dev/

Is there anything that need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

On Zeus this error can often be caused by incorrect file permissions. Try changing the file/directory permissions to 755.